# Is it possible for 3rd party scripts to access website files on localhost?

Tags: php, html, apache, raspberry-pi

I have a Apache page running on Raspberry Pi which uses `<script>` element to insert a 3rd party like-button which sends like data to their website, where it is stored. Would it be possible for the 3rd party to access HTML outside of `<script>` element and/or other pages in the same directory?

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible for the `<script>` tag to access other files in the same directory, though?

Comment: Explain in-depth on what you are trying to do. Is the <code> &lt;script&gt;</code> hosted on your local server or else where.

Comment: The `script` is stored on a third party site, but my page is on a Raspberry Pi web-server.

Comment: Need a bit more information like @Jayson_X suggests.   What you're asking seems to be confusing as to how HTML pages (and script) tags work.  When you mention; _Would it be possible for the 3rd party to access HTML outside of <script> element_, is this 3rd party under your control?

Comment: No, it is an external widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your device is connected to the internet, yes. Else, no. But for the third party to know where the request is coming from (e.g for facebook to render your Open Graph data accurately: like site name,url and the likes), you need to put your server online.